# How to resolve data from store?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store

Using route resolver I am trying to get a data from store as follows

```
export class GetActiveCustomerService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.store.select('customer').pipe(
      first(),
      map((data) => {
        return data.customer;
      })
    );
  }
}
```

The previous attempt always returns `null`

What is the correct way to resolve the data stored in the store?

**update 0**

This modification returns the expected result. But when refreshing the browser the data is null. I understand it is because of `take(1)`. If this is the route to achieve what I mentioned, how can I make the data survive refreshing?

```
export class GetActiveCustomerService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private store: Store<AppState>) {}

  private getActiveCustomer(): Observable<any> {
    return this.store.select('customers').pipe(take(1));
  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): any {
    return this.getActiveCustomer();
  }
}
```

**update 1**

I found this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58711499/615274 from someone who was facing a problem similar to mine. And the accepted solution uses `take(1)` or `first()`. But in my local when refreshing the obtained data it becomes `null`. What is the proper way to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Ngrx does not keep/save your data after reload. Use local storage or cookies to save your data before refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of what you're trying to achieve.

If the logic is to be able to refresh a page with a parameter (selectedProductId) in it and then display in a component (ProductDetailComponent) the corresponding data, taking into account the parameter, there's two solution for that using ngrx:

- Either you have somewhere in your store a selectedProductId that is updated using a Guard. Thus each time the page is refreshed the Guard set up the selectedProductId and you have a specific selector that will use the selectedProductId to get the proper data.
- Or use ngrx/router that will do most of the work for you and provide you with selectors for each parameter in your url.

Obviously in both case you have to ensure that:

- You call the back to get the data because everything is removed from the store when you refresh the page.
- You have a boolean in your store "isLoaded" that is set to false in the initial state and set to true when you receive the data, and you display a spinner or whatever you want while waiting for the data.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by making the state rehydrated. In the configuration of the property in question had been excluded from being persisted in the browser's storage. This caused the behavior described

```
export function storageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<AppState>) {
  const sync = storageSync<AppState>({
    features: [
      { stateKey: 'some' },
      { stateKey: 'another' },
      { stateKey: 'customer' } // <- here it was added
    ],
    rehydrate: true,

    storage: window.sessionStorage,
  });

  return sync(reducer);
}
```